# Where to find User TIming reports for Google Analytics for Mobile (iOS)

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am sending [User Timing](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/usertimings) data with `sendTimingWithCategory:withTimeInterval:withName:withLabel` but I can't seem to find these data on the Google Analytics reporting tool.

In my app, I try to capture different kinds of user timings, here are some code snippet:

```
    // duration1 & duration2 are instances of NSTimeInterval
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker sendTimingWithCategory:@"DurationOnApp" withValue:duration1 withName:nil withLabel:nil];

    [tracker sendTimingWithCategory:@"DurationOnSectionA" withValue:duration2 withName:nil withLabel:nil];
```

It just struck me: is it because I should give a value to `name` instead of leaving it as `nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked: 
`[tracker sendTimingWithCategory:@"DurationOnApp" withValue:duration1 withName:@"DurationOnApp" withLabel:nil];`.

Apparently, both category and name are necessary. User Timings are now appearing in Engagement --> App Speed

Comment: User Timings are now appearing in Engagement --> App Speed IS KEY INFORMATION !! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This works. Google have it wrong in doc. V3 of SDK.
NSTimeInterval is double, their SDK wants integer. Example on their web site is misleading.

```
- (void)onLoad:(NSTimeInterval *)loadTime {

    NSNumber* timeInterval = [NSNumber numberWithInt:((int) (loadTime * 1000))];
    [tracker sendTimingWithVariableCategory:@"resources"
                            withTimeInterval:timeInterval
                                    withName:@"high scores"
                                   withLabel:nil];
    ... // The rest of your onLoad: code.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The user timing is now at "Behavior -> App Speed"

Hope this helps :)